# Convert XML to Kotlin Data Class

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am pretty new to Kotlin and also to Retrofit. I am developing an android app using the [arXiv API](https://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual). They provide query results in **Atom XML** format. So, I am planning to use the **SimpleXML** converter with *Retrofit*. Now, I am having issue to generate the Kotlin data class from the Atom XML response.

For example, after sending a *GET* request to the url http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:electron&start=0&max_results=2, I get the following response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <link href="http://arxiv.org/api/query?search_query%3Dall%3Aelectron%26id_list%3D%26start%3D0%26max_results%3D2" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <title type="html">ArXiv Query: search_query=all:electron&amp;id_list=&amp;start=0&amp;max_results=2</title>
  <id>http://arxiv.org/api/dcXCKtYUYdD3VKb/I1GDXjTZxR0</id>
  <updated>2020-08-26T00:00:00-04:00</updated>
  <opensearch:totalResults xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">161478</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">0</opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">2</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
    <id>http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0102536v1</id>
    <updated>2001-02-28T20:12:09Z</updated>
    <published>2001-02-28T20:12:09Z</published>
    <title>Impact of Electron-Electron Cusp on Configuration Interaction Energies</title>
    <summary>  The effect of the electron-electron cusp on the convergence of configuration
interaction (CI) wave functions is examined. By analogy with the
pseudopotential approach for electron-ion interactions, an effective
electron-electron interaction is developed which closely reproduces the
scattering of the Coulomb interaction but is smooth and finite at zero
electron-electron separation. The exact many-electron wave function for this
smooth effective interaction has no cusp at zero electron-electron separation.
We perform CI and quantum Monte Carlo calculations for He and Be atoms, both
with the Coulomb electron-electron interaction and with the smooth effective
electron-electron interaction. We find that convergence of the CI expansion of
the wave function for the smooth electron-electron interaction is not
significantly improved compared with that for the divergent Coulomb interaction
for energy differences on the order of 1 mHartree. This shows that, contrary to
popular belief, description of the electron-electron cusp is not a limiting
factor, to within chemical accuracy, for CI calculations.
</summary>
    <author>
      <name>David Prendergast</name>
      <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Department of Physics</arxiv:affiliation>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>M. Nolan</name>
      <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">NMRC, University College, Cork, Ireland</arxiv:affiliation>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>Claudia Filippi</name>
      <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Department of Physics</arxiv:affiliation>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>Stephen Fahy</name>
      <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Department of Physics</arxiv:affiliation>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>J. C. Greer</name>
      <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">NMRC, University College, Cork, Ireland</arxiv:affiliation>
    </author>
    <arxiv:doi xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">10.1063/1.1383585</arxiv:doi>
    <link title="doi" href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1383585" rel="related"/>
    <arxiv:comment xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">11 pages, 6 figures, 3 tables, LaTeX209, submitted to The Journal of
  Chemical Physics</arxiv:comment>
    <arxiv:journal_ref xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">J. Chem. Phys. 115, 1626 (2001)</arxiv:journal_ref>
    <link href="http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0102536v1" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
    <link title="pdf" href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0102536v1" rel="related" type="application/pdf"/>
    <arxiv:primary_category xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="cond-mat.str-el" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="cond-mat.str-el" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0608371v1</id>
    <updated>2006-08-17T14:05:46Z</updated>
    <published>2006-08-17T14:05:46Z</published>
    <title>Electron thermal conductivity owing to collisions between degenerate
  electrons</title>
    <summary>  We calculate the thermal conductivity of electrons produced by
electron-electron Coulomb scattering in a strongly degenerate electron gas
taking into account the Landau damping of transverse plasmons. The Landau
damping strongly reduces this conductivity in the domain of ultrarelativistic
electrons at temperatures below the electron plasma temperature. In the inner
crust of a neutron star at temperatures T &lt; 1e7 K this thermal conductivity
completely dominates over the electron conductivity due to electron-ion
(electron-phonon) scattering and becomes competitive with the the electron
conductivity due to scattering of electrons by impurity ions.
</summary>
    <author>
      <name>P. S. Shternin</name>
      <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Ioffe Physico-Technical Institute</arxiv:affiliation>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>D. G. Yakovlev</name>
      <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Ioffe Physico-Technical Institute</arxiv:affiliation>
    </author>
    <arxiv:doi xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">10.1103/PhysRevD.74.043004</arxiv:doi>
    <link title="doi" href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.74.043004" rel="related"/>
    <arxiv:comment xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">8 pages, 3 figures</arxiv:comment>
    <arxiv:journal_ref xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Phys.Rev. D74 (2006) 043004</arxiv:journal_ref>
    <link href="http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0608371v1" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
    <link title="pdf" href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0608371v1" rel="related" type="application/pdf"/>
    <arxiv:primary_category xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="astro-ph" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="astro-ph" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

From the response, if we take a look at a **Author** tag, we get something like below (I have added line numbers for better readability),

```
1. <author>
2.     <name>David Prendergast</name>
3.     <arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Department of Physics</arxiv:affiliation>
4. </author>
```

Now, I can make a **Author** data class in Kotlin easily like below *without the 3rd line*

**Author.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class Author(
    var name: String = ""
) : Parcelable
```

***The one and only problem I am having to generate a data class for the Author tag is with the 3rd line of the code above xml file. I truly do not have any idea how to convert the 3rd line***

```
<arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Department of Physics</arxiv:affiliation>
```

***into a Kotlin data class***

Like 3rd line above, we also have

```
<opensearch:totalResults xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">161478</opensearch:totalResults>
<opensearch:startIndex xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">0</opensearch:startIndex>
<opensearch:itemsPerPage xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">2</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
```

*So, the summary of my question is, how to convert these kind of xml code into Kotlin data class?* Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean technically or conceptually? Conceptually, I assume you are having problems with the XML namespace definitions. They are usually just some string that is used as a prefix to tag names to avoid ambiguity, and sometimes to provide some additional context, but the exact content of the string could be anything and is more for humans than for the machine. Do you actually need that contextual information? If not, just ignore those.

Comment: Pardon me, but I am not getting what you are telling me to do. May be my lack of XML knowledge is liable for that. Yes, I know those are namespaces. But how can I convert them into my data class? For example,  I need an author's affiliation  information. But if I name the parameter as "arxiv:affiliation" in the Kotlin data class, then it shows me error which is obviously logical. So, here I am totally stuck about what to do... Should I just name the parameter as "affiliation" instead of "arxiv:affiliation" to get "Department of Physics" as the value? I have no clue:(